# Difference between transverse and transversal?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

As I understood it, two submanifolds $N_{1},N_{2}$ of a smooth manifold $M$ are *transverse* if at each $p \in N_{1} \cap N_{2}$, we have $T_{p}N_{1} + T_{p} N_{2} = T_{p}M$.

I have also seen authors who write the submanifolds $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ are *transversal*.

1. Which term is most commonly used?
2. Is there a difference in the usage of these terms (no matter how subtle)?

Comment: The authors who say transversal might have defined that on their text. You should be able to compare them and  see if the meanings are the same.

Comment: In some texts transversal is defined and used in exactly the same way. I ask the question as a means of gauging which term is better to use in my own writing.

Comment: In that case, then, in my opinion, transversal should be used as an adjective and transverse as a verb.

Comment: Thanks! please could you give an example of transverse used as a verb?

Comment: From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transverse One could say "this line transverses that curve since they are not tangent". I'm not native english so I might be wrong.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker either, but I once heard that "transverse" is an adjective, while "transversal" is a noun.